# How to handle ElementClickInterceptedException selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I try several ways to handle ElementClickInterceptedException

- like wait the driver
- get the focus and click.
- try to exec a javascript click

Do you have any ideas how to manage this kind of error ?

I can put a github repo in attachement

Comment: You need to provide us with WAY more details. The HTML structure would help, a screenshot of the overlay issue.... code attempted. Any details.

Comment: Hi, I put the case in attachement [image](https://ibb.co/b7WPmMC) I am also tring to delete in js the div

Answer (score 0):

I simply delete a blocking element in the dom.